# Spam filter fired inappropriately

Tags: feature-request

I asked a question with a title that was too short. I was informed of the minimum title length so I fixed my title and clicked "Post Your Question" again. I was then sent to the 'are you a human' page with the CAPTCHA. This seems to be an instance where the auto spam-filter shouldn't be triggered.

Comment: What makes you think it was inappropriate?

Comment: @Mike Sherov: I made an error, the system told me what I did wrong, I responded. To me, this sounds like the opposite of spam or bots.

Comment: the spam thing probably goes off if you try and do things too quickly, as that is indicative of 'botish' behaviour.  you get the same if you edit a post too many times in rapid succession.  you just fell fould of posting the question too quickly i suspect.  Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "spam" filter is the same as Stackoverflow.  On a recent [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/?p=263) interview, Jeff Atwood talks about how they had to block 2 Universities because students were consistently posting inappropriate questions.

As @Sam Holder suggested, I've had the spam thing go off for me when I try to do too many things at once.

(I don't know this for a fact) but I am pretty sure the whole spam thing is quite complicated.  At first, it tries to slow you down and eventually you get blocked.

For what it is worth, I don't understand how someone can down vote this question without a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the captcha as being a large enough inconvenience to code in exceptions for relatively unusual cases like this.